# Change programatically a radio button checked inside onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set programatically a radio button checked inside the *onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)* function,
but it is not working and the app crashes!

```
MenuItem thisItem;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

int opState = 4;        //--- Just a test: can be 1-4, ie check Button 4.

thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu1);  //--- Uncheck all buttons ---
thisItem.setChecked(false);
thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu2);
thisItem.setChecked(false);
thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu3);
thisItem.setChecked(false);
thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu4);
thisItem.setChecked(false);
```

I assume the above will set all the buttons to unchecked status. I am testing this on a real device so cannot run any diagnostics. Below check the value of opState and set the corresponding menu switch:

```
switch (opState) {
    case 1:
        thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu1);
            thisItem.setChecked(true);
            break;
    case 2:
            thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu2);
            thisItem.setChecked(true);
            break;
    case 3:
            thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu3);
            thisItem.setChecked(true);
            break;
    case 4:
            thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu4);
            thisItem.setChecked(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            item.setTitle("1");
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu2:
            item.setTitle("2");
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu3:
            item.setTitle("3");
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu4:
            item.setTitle("4");
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the menu file for the above:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu2"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu3"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu3"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu4"
            android:orderInCategory="4"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu4"/>
      </group>
  </menu>
```

The opState values are set in Name as in the section here:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            editor.putInt(Name, 1);
            editor.apply();
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            break;
```

Comment: Just the usual _App has unfortunately stopped working_.

Comment: Bro, this is so not correct: 
"I am testing this on a real device so cannot run any diagnostics."

Just keep your device plugged in via USB cable and you'll get your "diagnostics" a.k.a. log which is what we need in order to solve your problem. Post the error log please.

Comment: If you look through the logcat output you'll be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
At line 48, ie thisItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu1);

Comment: You should not call menu.findItem(R.id.menu1) in onCreate() method. Do it in onCreateOptionsMenu() instead. Take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private int getMenuIdByIndex(int index) {
        // index from 1
        switch (index) {
            case 1:
                return R.id.menu1;
            case 2:
                return R.id.menu2;
            case 3:
                return R.id.menu3;
            case 4:
                return R.id.menu4;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        int savedIndex = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("NAME", 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(getMenuIdByIndex(i));
            if (item != null) {
                item.setChecked(i == savedIndex);
            }
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu1:
                item.setTitle("1");
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("NAME", 1).apply();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu2:
                item.setTitle("2");
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("NAME", 2).apply();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu3:
                item.setTitle("3");
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("NAME", 3).apply();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu4:
                item.setTitle("4");
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("NAME", 4).apply();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I have no idea what exactly all this does, but it seems to work; although possibly the returned _opState_ value is often defaulting to 4.

Comment: If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. opState is set to 4, but you can change it as you wish

Comment: opState is actually a returned _sharedPreference_ value which varies from 1 to 4; and is assigned when the app starts.

Comment: then move simply its initialization in onCreate

Comment: I had it there from the start but now it is always 4. Let me check the code again.

Comment: opState always ends up as 4, ie button 4 always gets checked. Should we move this discussion to chat, or we will be in trouble?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106104/discussion-between-yital9-and-archdeacon).